# Why is it not possible to reopen TargetDataLine?

Tags: java, audio

If I try to open TargetDataLine again with another audio input device after I closed and stoped it then it only produces noise instead of a signal. Why?

Here is the code I'm talking about: https://gist.github.com/flextexmex/e2fad97b7e1af93d6c98

Answer (score 0):

This may not be related, but there was a faq about the TargetDataLine.
http://www.jsresources.org/faq_audio.html#multiple_tdl

> Why is in not possible to open more than one TargetDataLine at the same time?
>   Well, because it's a bug. The above is true for the Sun JDK up to version >1.4.2 on Solaris and Windows, and up to 1.4.1 on Linux. Beginning with version >1.5.0 for Solaris and Windows and version 1.4.2 for Linux there are the new >"Direct Audio Device" mixer that don't have this limitation.

Has updating to 1.50 fixed your issue?